# How to send email using the MFMailComposeViewController depending on the button pressed on a confirmation UiAlertView?

Tags: iphone, email

This must be real easy but apparently its not!

I was able to successfully show the alert and get the alert buttons working in **mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:** method but what I can't seem to understand is how do I stop the sending of the mail when someone presses NO button on the alert that goes like "Send Email?". I do not want to know what method i need to implement in order to capture the button. What I need to know is how does the MFMailComposeViewController send email after the SEND button is pressed? Apparently the didFinishWithResult method is the method thats hit only after the mail is sent/saved/cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user presses 'Send', you cannot stop the mail from being sent. This is not possible to do with the current SDK.

Comment: Really!!? I mean there is just no way to intercept the sending of the mail? That's odd.

Comment: No, this isn't odd at all. Remember with Apple, user is king...if they press "Send" in an Apple emailer, we as developers must assume they mean send. If you want to ask users "are you sure?" you should do that BEFORE pushing the mail composer.